# Size of allocated memory to a pointer changes when increment the pointer

Tags: c, pointers

```
 char *ptr = (char*)malloc(10);

    if(NULL == ptr)
    {
        printf("\n Malloc failed \n");
        return -1;
    }
    else if(argc == 1)
    {
        printf("\n Usage  \n");
    }
    else
    {
        memset(ptr, 0, 10);

        strncpy(ptr, argv[1], 9);

        while(*ptr != 'z')
        {
            ptr++;
        }

        if(*ptr == 'z')
        {
            printf("\n String contains 'z'\n");
            /* Do some more processing */
        }

       free(ptr);
    }
```

In the previous code, lets say that arguments to the program is: `Mixx`, the program gives a segmentation error.

And my question is:
When I do this in the while loop:

```
ptr++;
```

does this mean that the size of memory allocated to the pointer ptr also changes and that's why when I call the free() function it crashes.

Comment: I don't see this as a bad question. (Good description and code snippet). UV'd.

Comment: You read past the end of the string, as you don't check for the `\0` while you are in the `while` loop.

Comment: Unless `argv[1]` contains a `'z'`, the behavior is undefined *even before the `free()`*. Consequently, a conforming compiler may eliminate the `if(*ptr == 'z')`-check, since it cannot be false.

Comment: As always: Please ***don't*** cast the return value of `malloc` and friends

Answer (score 4):

Your hunch is correct: the behaviour of your program is *undefined*.

You *must* pass the *original* value of `ptr` to `free`.

(Also, `while(*ptr != 'z')` is vulnerable to overrunning your input. Consider checking for `\0` too.)

Comment: you mean that i need to count how many times ptr was incremented in the while loop and then decrement  it after  ?

Comment: @M.Cesar Wouldn't it be infinitely more sensible to accept the pointer returned by `malloc` into a `const` pointer, then take a copy of that for incrementing later?

Comment: That would be one way, but why not store the original value separately?

Comment: @underscore_d this is a training exercise and i was trying to determine why do i get a segmentation error , it is not an actual code

Comment: @M.Cesar Does the fact that it's a "training exercise" mean you're forced to keep using the same poor practices rather than doing things logically?

Comment: of course it doesn't but i am just saying that i was just trying to determine where does the error comes from in this case

Answer (score 1):

You can only pass to `free` a pointer that was returned by `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`.  What you passed it was a different pointer.  The fact that it points within the allocated block doesn't matter.

You need to keep track of the original pointer so it can be freed.

```
char *ptr = (char*)malloc(10);
char *ptr_sav = ptr;

...

free(ptr_sav);
```

Also, when you loop through the string, you're not checking to see if you reached the end of the string.  If you search past the null terminator, you access memory you don't own and invoke undefined behavior.

Add the check as follows:

```
while(*ptr != 'z' && *ptr != '\0')
```

Comment: This seems backwards. To avoid accidents, accept the original to a `*const`, and copy _that_ to a non-`const` for pointer arithmetic.